# Can I delete the Values in the mappings using delete keyword

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, mapping

```
mapping(IERC => contract) public testing;
delete testing[IERC];
```

In the above code snippet I want to delete contract type (value) using the delete keyword can it be possible?